# openstreetmap - How to set marker in center of screen?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker, osmdroid

I'm trying to display marker using `osmbonuspack_v4.8 ilb`. 
The marker was displayed but it place in `left-top` of screen.
I'm trying to *set* in center but can't. I don't konw the reason.

Please tell me the best way.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapController = (MapController) this.mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(52.221, 6.893);
        mapController.animateTo(center);
        //mapController.setCenter(center);

        //--- Create Overlay
        addMarker(center);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: what? are you trying to place an icon at the lat/lon at the center of the screen? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        mapView.setBottom(height);
        mapView.setRight(width);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapController = (MapController) this.mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(52.221, 6.893);
        mapController.animateTo(center);
        //mapController.setCenter(center);

        //--- Create Overlay
        addMarker(center);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: that doesn't look right. Setting the mapViews bottom and right specifically. And the location is hard coded

Answer (score 2):

Give this a whirl. It should plot your point at the center point of the screen.

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        IGeoPoint pt = mMapView.getProjection().fromPixels(width/2, height/2);
        mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);

        //--- Create Overlay
        addMarker(pt);
```